# How do i push objects in an array to next column in a csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, export-to-csv, puppeteer, async.js

I need help with pushing one of object into the next colums. As of now the csv file comes out, but everything is in the first column. how do I push the name to the second column?

basically what it looks like right now is

```
X    column1 column2
row1  AB
row2  AB
row3  AB

but what i want is

X    column1 column2
row1  A        B
row2  A        B
row3  A        B
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const utf8 = require('utf8');


(async function scrape () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = 'example.com';
    await page.goto(url);
    await fs.writeFile('out.csv', 'name, orgnummer\n', 'utf8');

    for( let i=0; i<5; i++){

            await page.waitForSelector('div.listing');

            const bolag = await page.$$('div.listing');
            for (const title of bolag){

                const nummer = await title.$eval('div.org-number', o =>
                o.innerText);
                const name = await title.$eval('a', h3=>
                h3.innerText);

                console.log (nummer, name);
                     await fs.appendFile('out.csv', `${nummer},${name}\n`, `utf8`,
                     function(err) { 
                        if (err) throw err;
                        // if no error
                });


            };

            await page.click('a.ssproff-right',{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
            await page.waitFor(500);

    }
    console.log("done");


})();
```

Comment: You wouldn't roll your own JSON or XML library, so why do it with CSV? There are tricky, non-obvious edge cases that will cost you time solving an already solved problem. Use an existing library and do something more constructive with your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Check it live here:https://repl.it/repls/VengefulBumpyDaemon

Use \t

```
  await fs.appendFile('out.csv', 'name \t orgnummer \n', 'utf8');
  //loop start
   await fs.appendFile('out.csv', `${nummer} \t  ${name}\n`, `utf8`,
                     function(err) { 
                        if (err) throw err;
                        // if no error
                });
  //loop end
```

Comment: thanks for response but it didnt really work as intended.

Comment: Now it just goes sideways (still in the same column and everything is wrapped in the 1st row. 

with \n it goes down 1 row for each loop, but stays in 1st column.

Comment: your example is bit confusing, not able to understand

Comment: Hi i posted it here as well, please check to see if you understand,
https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/fnju6b/help_with_export_to_csv/

what i want is 2 columns and then loop it downwards